# laravel install cmd error

Tags: laravel, cmd, composer-php

I try to install laravel in my win7 wamp server.
I follow this steps:

1. Download Laravel from: http://github.com/laravel/laravel/archive/master.zip.
2. Extract Laravel into the www folder for WAMP ([www.wampserver.com](http://www.wampserver.com)).
3. Download Composer from: http://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe
4. Enable openssl from all `php.ini` files.
5. Install Composer into the same directory `php.exe` is located.
6. Click on WAMP icon -> PHP -> PHP Extensions and enable: `php_openssl`, `php_curl`, `php_socket`.
7. Click on WAMP icon -> Apache -> Apache Modules and enable `ssl_module`
8. Open `cmd`.
9. Change into the directory where you extracted Laravel e.g: `cd C:\wamp\www\laravel`.
10. Type the command: `composer install`.

But I get error in cmd the package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting see `<//groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFLrc/discussion>` for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you already downloaded Laravel seperately, you don't need to install it, just get and update its dependencies:

```
composer update
```

Comment: I try this but still i get stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting see <//groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFLrc/discussion> for more details.